# VB.net for handheld device

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile, vbscript, windows-ce

I want to develop an application in VB.net for handheld device(Ticket machine in Bus and train).Is it possible to develop in Vb net.
Whether i need windows OS in my handheld device or any runtime environment only needed.
My hardware is ARM processor.

I want to run my application as standalone in my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have device with Windows Mobile on it it should be ok, though you'd have to find out what version of the .Net Compact Framework it has installed on it.

Here's more information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework

Comment: I dont have any Operating system.
I want to know is it possible to run vb.net application without any OS. ANy runtime environment only needed?
or i have to install windows mobile

Comment: Because .net is a relatively high level windows framework, you will need windows mobile to run it. As @ho says the .net compact framework is the way to go.

Comment: You don't need Windows Mobile (and it's unlikely you can license it anyway).  Windows CE would be a better fit for theis application, and lower cost.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs and hardware, the [Micro Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/default.mspx) runs .NET (though only C# is supported) on pretty resource-constrained devices.  It doesn't require an OS (it is the OS).